# How can I make this button change the background of my website when pressed?

Tags: html, css, button

So I like my current background color but want to also have a button that can change it to white for others. I am making it for my website. Please help! I checked the other ones like this and none of them have helped!

```css
#check {
  display: none;
}

.myBtn:active {
  background-color: white;
}

.myBtn:visited {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">Click here to change the background color</button>
```

this is what I have but it's not working

Comment: the style only changes the background colour of the button, also :visited is only for links

Comment: `:visited` is only valid for anchors (and areas) but not buttons

Comment: _"I like my current background color but want to also have a button that can change it to white for others"_ Changing it for you won't do anything for others. You'd need to modify the source

Comment: what I mean is like how can the color of the background of my site be changed by the button, also why does everyone dislike posts :') I didn't do anything wrong

Comment: Is anyone else able to help me figure out with my code why it could not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript will be required to achieve what you are asking for. As you currently have it implemented your CSS styling is styling the button and not the background of the page and the visited anchor is not valid on buttons.

```js
var bkgColorChangeBtn = document.getElementById("backgroundColorChangeButton")

bkgColorChangeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
})
```

```html
<body>
 <button id="backgroundColorChangeButton" class ="myBtn">Click here to change the background color</button>
</body>
```

Above is a working example of what you are trying to do. Note this won't persist when the user refreshes the page. If you want it to persist you will have to save a user setting into a database and recall the information on page render which goes beyond regular HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: the var code isn't working on my side, where do I paste it into? Also thank you so much for your help, I see it works on the code here but for some reason I'm struggling on where to put it in my code, also it's fine if it doesn't stay when leaving

Comment: You can either link an external JS page or you can put it in a script tag, as described in more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_JavaScript_within_a_webpage)

Comment: thank you, I had forgotten about script tags. It seems to be showing it works but when I actually run it,nothing changes not too sure why, it's in the script tags and everything. I have also been having trouble with my text not conforming to the width that I wanted it to do and the link colors have been acting funny, not too sure why do you think something could be interfering?

Comment: It is very strange but this isn't working on my side, how do you set a background color normally?

Comment: We need to scope this to one question so the width problem will need to be another question. You will need to provide a snippet or a JS Fiddle with your code to further debug the code. I would argue that since this snippet does in fact does answer your question it should be marked as the answer. The other problems you are experiencing are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: what is a JS fiddle apologies I just don't know where else to find this help, I've been looking it up